# <title> blank after installing Metatag

Tags: theming, 8, meta-tags

I have a theme that uses several template files like `page.html.twig`, `page--title.html.twig`, etc.

I installed Metatag to make my website more understandable when sharing links to it via LinkedIn. However, after installing the Metatag module, my  tags in all pages except admin are blank. I also tried to specify the title tag's content within Metatag as `[current-page:title] | [site:name]`, but the title tag is still empty

I know this is a common issue. I have found this online

> When using custom page template files, e.g., page--front.tpl.php, it
>   is important to ensure that the following code is present in the
>   template file: `<?php render($page['content']); ?>` or `<?php render($page['content']['metatags']); ?>`. Without one of these
>   being present the meta tags will not be displayed.

However, that looks like an advice for Drupal 7 only - and I don't know how to do this in a TWIG file used by Drupal 8. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: My TWIG files are as follows:

- page.html.twig: https://codeshare.io/5ezppb
- html.html.twig: https://codeshare.io/2KWnnE
- page-title.html.twig: https://codeshare.io/G8XeeD

Comment: can you share your `page.html.twig` and `html.html.twig` source codes?

Comment: Thanks, zhilevan. I edited the question and added the code.

Comment: Ping :) I'll be grateful for any advice on this.

Comment: your files seems Ok, I should test it by myself, do you develop your theme based on specified theme like boostrap theme  or zen or  omega? I mean what is your base and starter theme?

Comment: I have developed it from scratch few years back. However, I don't think the theme would be a problem - as I wrote above, I read online that this is a common issue related to the Metatag module and that one has to call the methods above - but that's PHP, so it would be usable in D7 .tpl files, not in TWIG in D8 - and that's the question, I think: how to call this in a D8 TWIG template.